# Recurring payment custom IPN field

Tags: paypal-ipn, gateway, payflowpro

I am creating recurring payments using PayflowPro Gateway, like this:

```
TRXTYPE=R&TENDER=C&PARTNER=PayPal&VENDOR=Acme&USER=Acme&PWD=a1b2c3d4&ACTION=A&PROFILENAME=RegularSubscription&AMT=42.00&ACCT=4012888888881881&EXPDATE=0203&START=12012013&PAYPERIOD=WEEK&TERM=12&OPTIONALTRX=S&OPTIONALTRXAMT=2.00&COMMENT1=First-time customer
```

once more:

```
#.................. API SPLIT SYNTAX for easier <field>-s' review

 TRXTYPE=R
&TENDER=C
&PARTNER=PayPal
&VENDOR=Acme
&USER=Acme
&PWD=a1b2c3d4
&ACTION=A
&PROFILENAME=RegularSubscription
&AMT=42.00
&ACCT=4012888888881881
&EXPDATE=0203
&START=12012013
&PAYPERIOD=WEEK
&TERM=12
&OPTIONALTRX=S
&OPTIONALTRXAMT=2.00
&COMMENT1=First-time customer
```

When the payments process later, an IPN notification is sent to us via the URL setup in Paypal.

Does anyone know how to set data for the `custom` field of IPN during the recurring payment creation process above?

`custom` doesn't seem to be a field in the PayflowPro recurring API.

Thanks.